# Mathematica's error by solving an ODE

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would know what is the problem with this Mathematica's code. Is there anyone that can give me an explanation of the bug, and also that can tell me how to improve the code?

```
V[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y - z;

m = 10;

DSolve[m*x''[t] == -Grad[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]*x[t], x[t], t]
```

Model of a particle in a potential-field. In this model we consider a particle as being a point of mass which describes a trajectory in space which is modeled by a function giving its coordinates in space as a function of time. The potential field is given by a function V : R^3 → R and the trajectory is a solution of the differential equation

[image]

Note this model assumes the particle is a point mass, which is certainly known to be false in many cases in which we use this model; for example, as a model of planetary motion.

Actual equation:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your equation is **malformed**: you have scalar on the left and vector on the right (grad of potential is vector).

Comment: @m0nhawk Why you call it malformed? Can you explain me a bit further?

Comment: `m` is scalar, `x[t]` is scalar too. `Grad[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]` is a **vector**, multiplied by `x[t]` it's vector. And scalar on the left didn't equal to the vector on the right. Maybe you mean `Laplacian` except for `Grad`?

Comment: And where this equation come from?

Comment: You still have a scalar on the left and a vector on the right. (both in the code and the equation)

Comment: You should check the updated code of mine, I missed `''` in the first version.

Comment: ok.. now sombody should go fix the wikipedia version!

Comment: @george fixed ; ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model#Examples_of_mathematical_models I hope that my changes are rigth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: don't trust [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model#Examples_of_mathematical_models). It good for some basic knowledge, but for something specific better use some field-specific sources.

The correct equation is:

[image]

And the correct code:

```
V[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y - z;
m = 10;
DSolve[m*{x''[t], y''[t], z''[t]} ==
    -(Grad[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t], z -> z[t]})
    , {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t]
```

Solution:

```
{{x[t] -> C[1] Cos[t/Sqrt[5]] + C[2] Sin[t/Sqrt[5]], 
  y[t] -> -(t^2/20) + C[3] + t C[4],
  z[t] -> t^2/20 + C[5] + t C[6]}}
```